# php - send variables on the fly to new php file

Tags: php, variables

Pressing a button i create a new php file on the fly. This file has a $variable that holds the result of a MYSQL query.
The file as an echo $variable statement that is converted to the value the $variable holds upon creation of the new file.

**I do not want this.**

What i need is that echo $variable is written in the new file has echo $variable.

**An similar example:**

```
<?php
$contents = 'Home';
echo $contents; 
?>
```

Is written in the new php created file as:

```
<?php echo Home; ?>
```

The $variable holds the value **Home**. Sadly is the value Home that is passed and not the original statement.

What do i have to do to write in the new file the original statement?

```
<?php echo $contents; ?>
```

Comment: can u clearify? what kind of new button? are you using some kind of scripting ? bash maybe?

Comment: `echo '$contents';`?

Comment: I have a php file with a form. I put some content in a text input and when i click a html submit button the value of the text input is send to a mysql database and a new php file with a an echo statement to the database filed is created. The problem is in the creation of the new pho file, because it creates the echo with the value of the query, wich is bad because on refresh of the page it does not update anymore. It should pass the echo and variable name, instead of the variable value.

Comment: echo '$contents'; -> does nort work... i already have tried, it passes the value, not the echo and variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following code.

```
$data = '<?php';
$data .= 'echo $contend; ?>';
$h = fopen('file.php','w');

fwrite($h,$data);
fclose();
```